# Django object create with one or more items (dynamically)

Tags: django, dictionary, django-models

Is there a way to use `model.objects.create(<dict>)`

Say my model has many optional fields. I would like to just pass a dict with whatever is there instead of manually assigning each field like:

`Model.objects.create(thing=data['prop'],...)`

Here's a more clear (pseudo code) example: Say i've got a model thats got

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  thing=models... // all these fields null=True, blank=True
  another=...
  possibly_another=...
  ...

data = {'thing': 'value for thing', 'another': 'value for another'}

MyModel.objects.create(data)
```

In this example my `data` doesn't have `possibly_another` and maybe more. I have tried doing this but i'm getting a positional arg error... I did some google-foo and i must not have my terms correct. (I'm more of a node/js guy)

Is there a way to just pass the dict and have the create method sort out what's there and not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform *dictionary unpacking* by using two consecutive asterisks (`**`):

```
MyModel.objects.create(**data)
```

If the dictionary contains for example `data = { 'a': 4, 'b': 2 }`, if you perform dictionary unpacking `f(**data)`, it will call the function with `f(a=4, b=2)`.

Note that for the missing values, you should have `default=...` parameters in these fields.

Comment: That's exactly what i needed to know! Thanks for the knowledge mate.

Comment: For sure. Defaults are set. I'll mark your answer correct asap. Thanks again. This is exactly the language info i was missing.